# get minimum and maximum line count from files within a directory

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have some 5 million text files under a directory - all of the same format (nothing special, just plain text files with some integers in each line). Id like to compute the maximum and minimum line count amongst all these files.

I started out by trying to write out all the line count like so (and then workout how to find the min and max from this list):

```
wc -l `find /some/data/dir/with/text/files/ -type f` > report.txt
```

but this throws me an error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/wc: Argument list too long
```

Perhaps there is a better way to go about this?

Maybe GNU-Parallel can help here somehow?

Comment: What if the minimum (or the maximum) is reached for more than one file? Do you want all the minimal (maximal) files? Or just one? If just one, does it matter which one?

Comment: Whatever approach you take, it's going to take a very long time (hours or possibly even days)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ah I did not think about it. Just one should be fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` exists to deal with this exact situation, and will work as long as the filenames involved don't contain spaces or newlines:

`find /some/data/dir/with/text/files/ -type f -print | xargs wc -l`

You could then sort based on the line count.  If you don't care about which specific files contain the minimum and maximum lines, you could then extract the line count field from each line of output, pipe it to `uniq`, and then the first line of the resulting output file is the minimum line count, and the last line is the maximum line count.

This does, admittedly, involve holding on to a lot of data through the process of computing the information you're looking for, so it might be better to pipe the output of the `find | xargs` pipeline to an `awk` script that just runs through each line and then tracks if each line count is smaller than the minimum it's seen so far, or larger than the maximum it's seen so far.

Comment: You could add that the GNU variants of `find` and `xargs` have the `-print0` and `-0` options, respectively, to deal with filenames that _do_ contain spaces or newlines.

Comment: @AdminBee even considering `find -print0` I'm not sure it's straightforward to handle the min/max requirement. Consider a filename `part1\n123 part2` (where `\n` is newline): how can you differentiate this output of one file from `wc -l` from two files `part1` and `part2`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use `find` to generate the list of files and pipe it onwards. This avoids having the shell attempt to expand all five million filenames in a single command

```
LC_ALL=C find -type f -exec wc -l {} + |
    awk '
        $2 != "total" {
            if (max=="" || $1>max) {max=$1; mxf=$2};
            if (min=="" || $1<min) {min=$1; mnf=$2};
        }
        END { printf "Min %d for %s, max %d for %s\n", min, mnf, max, mxf }
    '
```

`find` generates a list of *count filename*, which is passed to the `awk` script. This in turn does the heavy lifting, looking for - and reporting on - a maximum and a minimum value and filename.

This simplistic code does not handle file names containing spaces or non-printing characters.

Answer (score 3):

With recent versions of GNU utilities:

```
(
  printf '/dev/null\0' # for the case where's there's only one file
  find . -type f -print0
) |
  wc --files0-from=- -l |
  sed '1d;$d' | # remove /dev/null and total
  sort -n |
  sed '1b;$b;d'
```

Here, we're passing the list of files from `find` to `wc` via a pipe to `wc`'s stdin rather than via arguments, so it has a few advantages: no limit on number of arguments as we're not using the `execve()` system call. `wc` can start reading files as soon as `find` finds them. Compared to `xargs` or `-exec {} +` solutions, only one `wc` invocation is performed so we get at most one `total` line.

Note that GNU `wc` 8.30 at least mangles file names that contain newline characters. For instance, a file called `./a<newline>b` is rendered as `'./a'$'\n''b'` (here using ksh93-style `$'...'` quoting to express the newline character as `$'\n'`). In this instance, you can tell when `wc` does that mangling as all file paths should start with `.`. So when you see a `'`, that means that mangling has been performed.

You can undo it in the `zsh` shell with its `Q` parameter expansion flag:

```
$ wc -l './a
b'
146 './a'$'\n''b'
$ !! | read -r length file
$ printf '<%s>\n' $file ${(Q)file}
<'./a'$'\n''b'>
<./a
b>
```

In the general case, you can't tell when `wc` does that mangling though as for instance it would render a `a<newline>b` or `'a'$'\n''b'` filename the same:

```
$ wc -l 'a
b' "'a'$'\n''b'"
  146 'a'$'\n''b'
    1 'a'$'\n''b'
  147 total
```